# Can developers access unread mail in Mail app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, email

I'd like to show a list of recent unread messages in my app, and was wondering if I could do this without spending all the time to make my app work with email services? Or is there an open source library which deals with that and makes it easy?

Answer (score 1):

As you can imagine, accessing the users emails is a major security breach, and of course is not allowed.

You would have to use your own email client implementation and ask from the user to provide his account credentials.

An open source iOS email client project [is located here](http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/)